# Dependency injection w/ smart pointers in C++

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, valgrind, smart-pointers

I'm trying to implement the dependency injection pattern in a C++ project, performing injection manually (no framework). So I'm using a factory function to manually create the dependencies and pass them into the classes that use them. My problem is that when the root of the dependency graph (itself a class instance managed by a smart pointer) goes out of scope, its dependencies (smart pointers referenced within the class) don't get destroyed (valgrind shows lost blocks of memory).

I'm seeing this with just a basic example like this, where class A depends on class B:

```
class B{
public:
    B() {}
    ~B() {}
};

class A{

    std::unique_ptr<B> b_;

public:

    A(std::unique_ptr<B> b) : b_(std::move(b)) { }
    ~A(){}
};

namespace A_Factory {
    std::unique_ptr<A> getInstance(){
        return std::make_unique<A>(std::make_unique<B>());
    }
}

int main(void){
    auto a = A_Factory::getInstance();
    //do some A stuff
} //a goes out of scope and gets deleted?
```

So in this example I use `A_Factory::getInstance` to get A, so whatever is using A doesn't know about how A is created, nor does A know how its dependency is created. And it was my understanding that with smart pointers they'd automatically delete when going out of scope, *which hopefully would chain down the dependency graph once the root goes out of scope*. If I had to implement code to destroy the dependencies then I'm not getting much benefit from the smart pointer.

So I can't tell if I'm not setting up things right with the smart pointers, or perhaps valgrind isn't telling me what I think it means. My understanding with valgrind is that it's really only pointing out issues within the scope of *my code*, so if the standard library is deleting dependencies then valgrind may not reflect that. However when I run valgrind against a simple program using a smart pointer wrapped around a trivial class (no dependencies) it doesn't show any lost memory.

I'll also note that some examples I've seen here on stackoverflow have no worked for me, like not calling `std::move` in A's initialization list. And I'd like to avoid any raw pointers being passed around.

Comment: Did you try printing some debug messages from A and B destructors?

Comment: Just a pedantry, was the rvalue reference missing in `A(std::unique_ptr<B> b)` due to Markdown syntax? Would `&amp;` help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using g++ 4.8.5 which doesn't include make_unique but I've added Herb Sutter's suggested [make_unique implementation](https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/) and run your test under valgrind which shows no leaking.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&& ...args)
{
   return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T ( std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

class B{
public:
    B() {}
    ~B() {}
};

class A{

    std::unique_ptr<B> b_;

public:

    A(std::unique_ptr<B> b) : b_(std::move(b)) { }
    ~A(){}
};

namespace A_Factory {
    std::unique_ptr<A> getInstance(){
        return make_unique<A>(make_unique<B>());
    }
}

int main(void){
   auto a = A_Factory::getInstance();
}
```

Perhaps your problem stems from the make_unique implementation in whatever compiler you're using?

Comment: I discovered the issue thanks to following Howard's answer, however I did discover a pretty significant difference in memory loss reported by valgrind depending on implementation. After fixing the issue, g++ 5.4.0 (Ubuntu) showed no issues, however LLVM 8.1.0 (mac OS Sierra) still showed numerous loss records.

Answer (score 0):

I've instrumented your code with print statements in *all* constructors, and in the destructors.  Furthermore I've disabled all compiler-generated constructors to make sure they don't run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class B{
public:
    B() {std::cout << "B()\n";}
    ~B() {std::cout << "~B()\n";}
    B(const B&) = delete;
};

class A{

    std::unique_ptr<B> b_;

public:

    A(std::unique_ptr<B> b) : b_(std::move(b)) {std::cout << "A()\n";}
    ~A(){std::cout << "~A()\n";}
    A(const A&) = delete;
};

namespace A_Factory {
    std::unique_ptr<A> getInstance(){
        return std::make_unique<A>(std::make_unique<B>());
    }
}

int main(void){
    auto a = A_Factory::getInstance();
    //do some A stuff
}
```

This program outputs for me:

```
B()
A()
~A()
~B()
```

I'm counting one constructor for each destructor.  Do you see the same thing with your compiler?  If so, all is well.

Comment: This lead me down the path towards finding the real culprit. The example code I provided did not accurately reflect the code I was testing with one key difference: each class was an implementation of a pure virtual abstract class, and I had not declared virtual destructors in the abstract class. So after doing so the destructors were called and there were no more lost blocks of memory reported by valgrind.

Comment: Glad I could help.